# Error Referencing Sub Query in Group By on Main Select statement in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run the following T-SQL code

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(ro.[Date processed at hub]), 
    DATENAME(mm, ro.[Date processed at hub]), 
    YEAR(ro.[Date processed at hub]), 
    COUNT(ro.[Date processed at hub]) as 'No of Orders', 
    COUNT(ro.[Date processed at hub]) * 5.72 as 'Cost', 
    (SELECT COUNT(ite.[Date return created]) 
     FROM [ZoomBI].[dbo].[ReboundOrder] Ite 
     WHERE ro.[Order Reference] = ite.[Order Reference]) AS NoofItems
FROM 
    [ZoomBI].[dbo].[ReboundOrder] ro 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(ro.[Date processed at hub]), 
    DATENAME(month, ro.[Date processed at hub]), 
    MONTH(ro.[Date processed at hub])
ORDER BY
    MONTH(ro.[Date processed at hub])
```

Example:

`Order` table

```
OrderNumber   Date Processed
----------------------------
    123       12/09/2020
```

`Item` table

```
OrderNumber   SKU       ReturnCreated
-------------------------------------
    123       MS1234    12/09/2020
    123       MS1235    13/09/2020
    123       MS1235    02/10/2020
```

Result:

```
Month       Year   NoofOrders   NoofItems
-----------------------------------------
September   2020        1           2
```

I need to be able to count the number of items for that order per month and year however,

I am getting this error

> Column 'Order Reference' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Even though it is not used in the main select?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* using it in the main `SELECT`, because it is being fed into the correlated subquery.

Instead, you can do this as a join, then sum that up. I've done this as an `APPLY` but you could also do a `JOIN`

```sql
SELECT 
  month(ro.[Date processed at hub]), 
  DATENAME(mm, ro.[Date processed at hub]), 
  YEAR(ro.[Date processed at hub]), 
  COUNT(*) as [No of Orders], 
  COUNT(*) * 5.72 as Cost,
  SUM(ite.NoofItems) AS NoofItems
FROM 
  [ZoomBI].[dbo].[ReboundOrder] ro 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(*) AS NoofItems
    FROM 
      [ZoomBI].[dbo].[ReboundOrder] Ite 
    WHERE 
      ro.[Order Reference] = ite.[Order Reference]
  ) AS ite
GROUP BY 
  YEAR(ro.[Date processed at hub]), 
  DATENAME(month, ro.[Date processed at hub]), 
  month(ro.[Date processed at hub])
order by 
  month(ro.[Date processed at hub])
```

Note that `EOMONTH` can be more efficient as a grouping value than `YEAR` and `DATENAME`, so try this

```sql
SELECT 
  month(EOMONTH(ro.[Date processed at hub])), 
  DATENAME(mm, EOMONTH(ro.[Date processed at hub])), 
  YEAR(EOMONTH(ro.[Date processed at hub])), 
  COUNT(*) as [No of Orders], 
  COUNT(*) * 5.72 as Cost,
  SUM(ite.NoofItems) AS NoofItems
FROM 
  [ZoomBI].[dbo].[ReboundOrder] ro 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(*) AS NoofItems
    FROM 
      [ZoomBI].[dbo].[ReboundOrder] Ite 
    WHERE 
      ro.[Order Reference] = ite.[Order Reference]
  ) AS ite
GROUP BY 
  EOMONTH(ro.[Date processed at hub])
order by 
  EOMONTH(ro.[Date processed at hub])
```

> Side note: `COUNT(NonNullValue)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)`

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface that works perfectly, would that take into account the dates for that given month?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: or should I add  and  EOMONTH(ite.[Date return created] ) = EOMONTH(ro.[Date processed at hub]) So that it only picks the orders and Items for that given month as an item for that order might be in another month

Comment: You mean an order can be in one month and an item in a different month? That's an unusual schema. Yes you would need that if that is what you want, but you could do it better like this `WHERE ro.[Order Reference] = ite.[Order Reference] AND ite.[Date return created] >= DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(ro.[Date processed at hub], -1)) AND ite.[Date return created] < DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(ro.[Date processed at hub]))` this means it will use indexes properly